# genealogytree -- marriage puts a horizontal line on the photo

Tags: genealogytree

When I try to add the marriage date to one of the basic examples in the user guide, I get a horizontal line that overlaps the photo:[image: problem]

Here my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[
    processing=database,
    database format=medium marriage below,
    node size=2.4cm,
    level size=3.5cm,
    level distance=6mm,
    %...
    list separators hang,
    name font=\bfseries,
    surn code={\textcolor{red!50!black}{#1}},
    place text={\newline}{},
    date format=d/mon/yyyy,
    %...
    tcbset={male/.style={colframe=blue,colback=blue!5},
        female/.style={colframe=red,colback=red!5}},
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
        halign=left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
        \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
        if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
            underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom DBimage]
                ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}},
        }{},
    },
]
sandclock
{
child{
    g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
        male,
        name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
        birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
        marriage={1800-01-01}{},  %<== my modification to the guide's example
        death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker},
        image={Carl_Friedrich_Gauss.jpg},
    }
    p[id=GauxCarl1777]{
        female,
        name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
        birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
        marriage={1800-01-01}{},  %<== my modification to the guide's example
        death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
        profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker},
        image={Carl_Friedrich_Gauss.jpg},
    }

}
}
\end{genealogypicture}




\end{document}
```

Does someone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various possible solutions for this. The simplest is to change to a database format that does not draw a line, such as `medium`. In this case the marriage is printed in between the birth and the death.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[
    processing=database,
    database format=medium,
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
        halign=left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
        \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
        if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
            underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom image=\gtrDBimage]
            ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}},
        }{},
    },
]
sandclock{
    child{
        g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
            male,name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
            birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
            marriage={1800-01-01}{},
            death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
            profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker},
            image={Carl_Friedrich_Gauss.jpg},
        }
    }
    child{
        g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
            female,name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
            birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
            marriage={1800-01-01}{},
            death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
            profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker},
        }
    }
}
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

A second possibility is to change the definition of `medium marriage below` to remove the line. The definitions are listed in the file `gtrcore.node.code.tex`, and they can be redefined by adding modified code to your own document after loading `genealogytree`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\gtrDeclareDatabaseFormat{medium marriage below}{}{%
  \gtrPrintName%
  \begin{gtreventlist}%
    \gtr@list@event@birth%
    \gtr@list@event@floruit%
    \gtr@list@event@death%
  \end{gtreventlist}%
  \gtr@print@infolist%
  \gtr@ifmarriagedefined{%
  \begin{gtreventlist}\gtr@list@event@marriage\end{gtreventlist}}{}%
  % was: \gtr@ifmarriagedefined{\tcbline\begin{gtreventlist}\gtr@list@event@marriage\end{gtreventlist}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[
    processing=database,
    database format=medium marriage below,
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
        halign=left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
        \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
        if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
            underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom image=\gtrDBimage]
            ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}},
        }{},
    },
]
sandclock{
    child{
        g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
            male,name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
            birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
            marriage={1800-01-01}{},
            death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
            profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker},
            image={Carl_Friedrich_Gauss.jpg},
        }
    }
    child{
        g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
            female,name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
            birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
            marriage={1800-01-01}{},
            death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
            profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker},
        }
    }
}
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

To extend this solution a bit you can test if there is an image and only print the line for nodes without an image, and for example a bit of vertical space otherwise.

MWE, only the relevant part of the redefinition shown:

```
\gtr@ifmarriagedefined{%
  \ifdefvoid{\gtrDBimage}{\tcbline}{\vspace{2mm}}%
  \begin{gtreventlist}\gtr@list@event@marriage\end{gtreventlist}}{}%
```

Result:

[image]

Or add the `\tcbline` in both cases, both make the line 24mm shorter in case there is an image:

```
\gtr@ifmarriagedefined{%
  \ifdefvoid{\gtrDBimage}{\tcbline}{%
  \tcbline@ {\kvtcb@leftupper +\@totalleftmargin +24mm}}%
  \begin{gtreventlist}\gtr@list@event@marriage\end{gtreventlist}}{}%
```

Result:

[image]